# Blocked with Android studio compilation issue ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-build

With Android studio v0.8.2, I am blocked with the following exception. With the beta release it was working very well. I have updated my IDE to 0.8.2 and deleted my target directory and trying to build again. I am struck now.

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/gopinath/code/bitbucket/android/productionapp/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.jakewharton.hugo/hugo-runtime/1.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)﻿

As reported by the error, the file is actually missing in the mentioned path. For my other project in which I have hugo-runtime, the file exists and compilation is proper.

Is anyone else facing this issue? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so I fixed it by create new project and copied useful files to new project.

Comment: if anyone still having this issue also try checking this answer only this worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504972/9963757

Answer (score 1):

Posting so that it might help others:

I ran into this issue as well. The error is from `ManifestMerger` and it made me believe it has something to do with my manifest file and that took me on a wrong path. This error can also happen in case of an **invalid XML file in your resources**. In my case it was a layout file that got left over from a merge conflict with nothing in it (an empty layout file) which in turn caused the issue. it also cloud be any other xml file so I would suggest opening your xml resources one at a time and see if there is any error in them (you will get the lint error when opening the file)

Comment: i checked all the solutions but this was the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Click the build tab and clean Project. Boom!

Comment: Didn't help me :(

Comment: it never work. I removed even .android and .gradle folder caches along with build folder and fire Invalidate Cache and Restart after that.