# "com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException" in DisplayingBitmaps

Tags: android, android-studio

When i am buiding the google' android demo [DisplayingBitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

I came across the below problem:

```
Error:Execution failed for task         
:Application:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException:    
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 6; The 
processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Comment: did you find a fix for this error?

Comment: @user2525211    I have built it from an entirely new project and run it successfully,you can get it from here. https://github.com/Leaking/Android_Learning_Demo/tree/master/DisplayingBitmaps

Comment: if anyone still having this issue also try checking this answer only this worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504972/9963757

Answer (score -1):

This error can be the result of many scenarios,

The most common one is when you have an **invalid XML file in your resources**. In my case it was a layout file that got left over from a merge conflict with nothing in it (an empty layout file) which in turn caused the issue. it also cloud be any other xml file so I would suggest opening your xml resources one at a time and see if there is any error in them (you will get the lint error when opening the file)

Another case is that you might have an error in your AndroidManifest file which in that case you can find the error using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889558/2529309)

Comment: nothing like that. Project was running fine before I added android library dependency. After which it start throwing error. Just remove library dependecy and it start running without any problem.