# MergeFailureException when trying to build project

Tags: android, gradle, build

i am trying to convert my app to an android library and start some activity from some android project that depend on the app, after building i am getting this errors, i have not idea wy it look like the manifests are valids and have nothing that can couse that

```
com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\android-app\app\gradleBuild\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\android-app\app\gradleBuild\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:583)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:74)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\android-app\app\gradleBuild\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2.loadLibraries(ManifestMerger2.java:695)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2.merge(ManifestMerger2.java:127)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2.access$600(ManifestMerger2.java:54)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$Invoker.merge(ManifestMerger2.java:1166)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:544)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\android-app\app\gradleBuild\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$FileStreamProvider.getInputStream(ManifestMerger2.java:812)
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2.loadLibraries(ManifestMerger2.java:686)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Do you have this file generated - C:\android-app\app\gradleBuild\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: no i dont know way the merge is fail

Comment: The problem is that gradle cannot find the specified file. Are you running the build inside or out of android studio? Seems like there is a clean or delete that is happening during the process.

Comment: if anyone still having this issue also try checking this answer only this worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504972/9963757