# Execution failed for task :app:processDebugmanifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest-merging

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

Comment: post your code..

Comment: This generally regarding library are you using xml libraries

Comment: If you are facing this issue try to provide its dependacies using transitive=false

Comment: You need to use the same android support library version.@Sachin Kumar Singh

Comment: if anyone still having this issue also try checking this answer only this worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504972/9963757

Answer (score 12):

Try adding this line to your manifest file.

`<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`>

Answer (score 4):

Check you AndroidManifest.xml file, Maybe you can find error there.
If no problem, please check this in manifest tag like this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
     ...........................................
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well. The error is from `ManifestMerger` and it made me believe it has something to do with my manifest file and that took me on a wrong path. This error can also happen in case of an **invalid XML file in your resources**. In my case it was a layout file that got left over from a merge conflict with nothing in it (an empty layout file) which in turn caused the issue. it also cloud be any other xml file so I would suggest opening your xml resources one at a time and see if there is any error in them (you will get the lint error when opening the file)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the AndroidManifes.xml just contains

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
     </manifest>
```

So, My issue was solved by adding the following lines in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  ...
 </manifest>
```